# Pass environment.ts To Angular Library Module

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-library

I am building an Angular library which will expose a service and middleware to perform authentication when imported into other Angular apps.

Before trying to pull this module into a standalone [Angular Library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#getting-started), it was relying on the `environment.ts` file in the application (I just imported it like so: `import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';`).

How do I pass the environment file to a module that will now be imported into my Angular application?

Or is it better to pass the `environment` file, as JSON, to each service and piece of middleware I am exposing?

Comment: A better solution can be found at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328785/angular-2-import-service-based-on-environment/61586551#61586551

Answer (score 7):

The best way to achieve that is to expose a configuration object for you module, instead of using the environment file direct. Something like:

```js
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface LibConfig {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

export const LibConfigService = new InjectionToken<LibConfig>('LibConfig');
```

in your main module:

```js
export class LibModule {

  static forRoot(config: LibConfig): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide:  LibConfigService,
          useValue: config
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

and so when adding the library to your project's module imports, you can do:

```js
LibModule.forRoot({
  foo: environment.foo,
  bar: environment.bar
})
```

and in the lib, you can access the config with something like:

```js
  private libConfig: LibConfig;

  constructor(@Inject(LibConfigService) private config) {
    this.libConfig = config;
  }

  public getConfig(): LibConfig {
    return this.libConfig;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked nice!
One small notice: in main module I had to add ModuleWithProviders<LibModule> and in constructor: @Inject(LibConfigService) private config: LibConfig to avoid errors :). But this worked excellent!

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a module using the forRoot pattern.

On your library module:

```
export const OPTIONS = new InjectionToken<LibraryOptions>('options');

@NgModule({...})
export class LibraryModule {

  static forRoot(options: LibraryOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
  return {
   ngModule: LibraryModule,
   providers: [
   {
     provide: OPTIONS,
     useValue: options
   }]
  }
 }

}
```

then inject OPTIONS token on your components and services to access the options.

```
constructor(@Inject(OPTIONS) options: LibraryOptions){}
```

to use the LIbrary:

```
imports:[LibraryModule.forRoot({...})]
```